# IntelliJ 2020.3 Export Settings Error - Writing File

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

**Any workarounds are welcomed. Here is the IntelliJ *[YouTrack issue filed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252588)*.**

## Expect

Export and import IntelliJ settings.

## Observe

After upgrading to IntelliJ 2020.3 (Community Edition) there is an error in exporting settings.

### Steps

1. *File* > *Manage IDE Settings* > *Export Settings* > Error occurs

> Error Writing File 
> Error writing settings. 
> java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException: /Users/adamhurwitz/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/options/code.style.schemes

[image: Export Settings]

2. *File* > *Manage IDE Settings* > *Import Settings* > No settings are found.

> Invalid File 
> The file /Users/adamhurwitz/Desktop/settings.zip contains no settings to import. 
> Please make sure it was generated by File | Export Settings feature.

[image: Import Settings]

## Configuration

- IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Community Edition)
- Build #IC-203.5981.155, built on November 30, 2020
- Runtime version: 11.0.9+11-b1145.21 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
- macOS 10.16
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
- Memory: 1979M
- Cores: 16
- Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, com.google.gct.core, cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id, com.developerphil.adbidea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete `/options/code.style.schemes` file. It's not used by the IDE and is a leftover from some old version.

Follow [the bug in YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252588) for updates.

Comment: I've removed `code.style.schemes` from the directory on my Mac *Users/{myusername}/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/options* and IntelliJ import/export now works as expected.